# Cannot list directory on IIS FTP server on Azure, even after configuring Azure inbound rules and Windows firewall

Tags: azure, iis, ftp, azure-virtual-machine

I'am running Windows Server 2012 in Azure, and I've configured the FTP server in IIS. When I try to connect the server, it accepts the username and password and log me in but not showing the directory listing.

1. I've tried using FileZilla FTP client to connect and it saying the same error.

   ```
   Status: Resolving address of jothiprakashanandan.southindia.cloudapp.azure.com
   Status: Connecting to 104.211.244.241:21...
   Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
   Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
   Status: Logged in
   Status: Retrieving directory listing...
   Command:    PWD
   Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
   Command:    TYPE I
   Response:   200 Type set to I.
   Command:    PASV
   Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
   Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
   Status: Disconnected from server
   ```
2. The inbound rule of Azure is this:

   [image: Azure Inbound Rule]
3. The VM's firewall inbound rule. [image: VM's inbound rule]
4. However when I try to login from the VM's browser it is working fine and showing the directory list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Azure, we should deploy the **passive mode FTP**, we should **add** data channel ports range in **FTP Firewall Support**, then add those ports to **NSG** and **windows firewall inbound rules**.

[image]

By the way, although the windows firewall seems to allow all traffic that’s required, we also need to enable stateful FTP filtering on the firewall:

```
netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFtp enable
```

Then restart the FTP windows service and we should be up and running:

```
net stop ftpsvc
net start ftpsvc
```

Here is a similar [case](https://serverfault.com/questions/822715/how-to-access-my-ftp-sever-over-the-internet/822819#822819), same error as you, please refer to it.

Check which port does the FTP site listen on:
[image]

Comment: Actually i am having problems after restarting the server in the Azure portal. I'll confirm once after a try.

Comment: @JothiPrakashAnandan OK, after the VM started, we should check the data channel port range, and open them in VM's NSG and windows firewall inbound rules.

Comment: Okay jason. I'll check them both and let you know.

Comment: The FTP server is working fine in the VM. and when i try to connect from the local machine using filezilla it is showing timeout error. 
`Status: Resolving address of jothiprakash.southindia.cloudapp.azure.com
Status: Connecting to 52.172.10.61:2500...
Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error: Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Resolving address of jothiprakash.southindia.cloudapp.azure.com
Status: Connecting to 52.172.10.61:2500...
Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error: Could not connect to server`

Comment: I've used this link for creating and configuring the Azure VM. [Configuring Azure VM](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/enable-ftp-access-on-windows-azure-vm/)

Comment: @JothiPrakashAnandan can you telnet 2500 the Azure VM from your local machine?

Comment: `Connecting To 52.172.10.61:2500...Could not open connection to the host, on port
 23: Connect failed` This was the result of telnet ping

Comment: @JothiPrakashAnandan I had test in my lab, I can't telnet your port 2500, please add port 2500 in your VM windows firewall

Comment: @JothiPrakashAnandan also we should run this command in the Azure V M,  use command line to run" netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFtp enable"

Comment: @JothiPrakashAnandan according to your post, you add port 21 to windows firewall, but FTP listen on port 2500, so should add port 2500 on VM's firewall.

Comment: [Security Group snapshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwOoezghNRUiMHk2WWt1ZDQ1alU). and [VM's snapshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwOoezghNRUiVU81d1kyXzNsX1U). So far i haven't found any configuration problems @jason

Comment: @JothiPrakashAnandan can you telnet your VM's public ip address? "telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 2500"

Comment: it is showing me this when i ping using telnet   `Connection failed: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 52.172.10.61:2500`

Comment: @JothiPrakashAnandan I can't telnet you ip address with port 2500, can you telnet your localhost 2500 from the Azure VM. and check the FTP listen on which port.

Comment: @JothiPrakashAnandan we can right cliect you FTP site, and select "edit bindings", in this way, we can find the ftp site listen on.

Comment: I checked both the ports 21 and 2500 and it is showing the following errror.. `C:\Users\jothiprakash>telnet 52.172.10.61 2500
Connecting To 52.172.10.61...Could not open connection to the host, on port 2500
: Connect failed

C:\Users\jothiprakash>telnet 52.172.10.61 21
Connecting To 52.172.10.61...Could not open connection to the host, on port 21:
Connect failed`

Comment: login your azure vm, and try telnet, "telnet 127.0.0.1 2500"

Comment: It has entered into telnet. Working perfect with 2500 port.

Comment: @JothiPrakashAnandan Ok, we should check the Azure Vnet subnets' security group. select your virtual network, in the settings select subnets, then we can find the subnets' security group, by default is none.

Comment: We can't through the public telnet 52.172.10.61 with port 2500, because something block it, In azure, NSG, VM's firewall and subnets' security group will block it, so we should check them. for test, we can turn off azure  vm windows firewall, make sure there is no security group with subnets, and open port 2500 on NSG, then try to use telnet to test it.

Comment: Great @jason now i've changed the NSG and now telnet is okay. `Status: Connecting to 52.172.10.61:2500...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response: 220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command: USER jothiprakash
Response: 530 Valid hostname is expected.
Error: Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to 52.172.10.61:2500...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response: 220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command: USER jothiprakash
Response: 530 Valid hostname is expected.
Error: Could not connect to server`

Comment: I still can't directly connect using filezilla.

Comment: For test, you can use IE to connect the FTP site, ftp://52.172.10.61:2500

Comment: ftp:// 52.172.10.61:2500

Comment: `530 Valid hostname is expected` This is the warning showing in filezilla. Although i can ping using telnet from my local machine to VM, i can't connect to the VM via FileZilla.

Comment: You just have add DNS name to the username like `"jothiprakash.southindia.cloudapp.azure.com"|jothiprakash` and the error is resolved and directory listing is available. Thank you for helping @jason

Comment: Great, if it helps, please mark it as an answer. It will help others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136413/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-jothi-prakash-anandan).

Answer (score 0):

It is usually necessary to restart the *Microsoft FTP service* after enabling the FTP server rules in Windows firewall to have the change take an effect.

Or restarting a whole machine.

See *my guide* to [Installing an FTP Server on Windows using IIS](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server#restart).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with Azure network NSG. you need to enable the port range on which data is getting transferred.[image: Data connection port range]

Added new rule in NSG to open this port range and it worked.