# How to access azure VM directory from my machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I want to give read-write access to a specific folder in Azure VM to someone from his/her machine at home. I do not want him to give access to login to the machine, but some way so he/she can reach the directory and make changes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want him to give access to login to the machine, but some way
>   so he/she can reach the directory and make changes. Any ideas?

According to your description, maybe we can deploy **FTP** on that VM. In this way, he/she can access this folder on internet, we can give them read-write permission.

Here [a similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42266512/cannot-list-directory-on-iis-ftp-server-on-azure-even-after-configuring-azure-i/42266741#42266741) about how to deploy FTP on windows server, please refer to it.